# Problem iterating over images in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am trying to iterate over some images, and call a method on them. The actual method is irrelevant to my problem, so I have tried to put a minimal example of my issue below :

```
    df = pd.read_csv('csv_file.csv')
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
 -->    with open('ImagesFolder\\' + df.LocalImage, 'rb') as images_file:
        callMethod()
```

Error on the "with" line (see arrow).

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Series
```

It should be opening a local image, with the name gotten from the CSV file, and calling the method. Instead the "with" is causing the above issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `for index, row in df.iterrows()` but in every iteration you use the entire column\Series (`df.LocalImage`) to generate the file path.

What you should do instead:

```
for path in df.LocalImage:
    with open('ImagesFolder\\' + path, 'rb') ...
```

Or even better, use `os.path.join`:

```
for path in df.LocalImage:
    with open(os.path.join('ImagesFolder', path), 'rb') ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @DeepSpace.

You could also transform Series to String by

```
df.LocalImage.to_string(index=False)
```